# Read-only file system

Tags: linux

I'm new with linux, I was running Virtual box while the computer crashed, so i forced the computer to shutdown, when i started the computer again it seems like there is something went wrong with the hard disk volumes, so I ran the following

```
lvm vgscan
lvm vgchange -ay
e2fsck -f /dev/cg_rotanpc/lv_root
e2fsck -f /dev/cg_rotanpc/lv_home
exit #every thing started successfully after the exit [OK]
```

and restarted the computer 
and now when ever i try to do anything with the computer it gives me an error about

```
Read-only file system
```

now i can open any application even the browser because of the read only issue

how can i solve this issue ?

your help will be very very appreciated

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic because it is dubious that this question is being asked in a professional capacity. This is something for your local Linux administrator to begin diagnosing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your file system has been mounted on /

Run the following command

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Comment: It is very likely that the file system got automatically mounted read-only because of a file system error. I wouldn't write to it (= mount it rw) before a run of fsck.